# Disable a text on linked box

Tags: javascript, wordpress, text, plugins

I have a box and a text on box. My box has linked to an address.

When I try to click on box for going to link the text on it will preventing me to click on box, so I need to the text be there but don't get recognize from clicking. I hope make my point.

Here a sample output from my plugin:

```
<span class="tc_seat_unit tc_set_seat ui-selectee" id="*" data-tt-id="*" style="background-color: #B00A0D;">
    <p class="tc_custom_seat_number">54</p>
</span>
```

And this is what I saw in site loaded:

[image: HTML output]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<span>` cannot contain a `<p>` element.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Without seeing the issue in action (and the code you provided isn't enough to reproduce the problem) we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your CSS class  `.tc_custom_seat_number`

user-select: none; display: block;

Or try to do do this inline as follows:

```
<p class="tc_custom_seat_number" style="user-select: none; display: block;">54</p>
```

Comment: ```
        .tc_custom_seat_number{
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 10pt;
   font-weight:300;
            color: #fff;            
   user-select: none;
   text-align: center;
   top:50%;
   left:25%;
        }
  ```
  not working !

Comment: exactly that's my problem with this plug-in. it does not give me the link ! the links has been generated by js and php inside ! but my real problem is to make a text as a just showcase and do nothing more.. hope make my point

Comment: Trace plugin behaviors with dev tools in your browser. F12 ;) . if your plugin doesn't  work, here have no support.